# Auto-height inline when block not fit this inline

Tags: html, css, block, inline

I have some "block" in p which should be right-aligned:

```
<p>text at line
    <span style="display: block; float: right">
        <span class="tag">
           tag1
        </span>
        <span class="tag">
           tag2
        </span>
        <span class="tag">
           tag3
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
<hr>
Some text after hr
```

CSS:

```
.tag {
    background-color:red;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

All right but on small screens I have some issue:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/3pcjqww0/

Comment: Paragraphs shouldn't contain block elements (or elements with `display;block`).

Comment: Ok, but if change Paragraph to span which is "inline" the result will be same https://jsfiddle.net/3pcjqww0/1/ What error I have in this case?

Comment: Spans shouldn't contain block items either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `p` to a `div`, and add these styles:

```
div {
  line-height: 1.8em;  //this prevents the tags from overlapping the text on small screens
}

hr {
  clear: both;         //this keeps the horizontal rule at 100% width
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghwzhfkd/)

Comment: Thank you very much for working result and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of achieving what I think you're looking for is by using `float: right` as opposed to using `margin` in css.

`.tag {
    background-color:red;
    float: right;
    padding:5px;
}`

https://jsfiddle.net/tuna7u0x/